`Error: invalid address` when I try to deploy script
I am having this issue,
bilgekaangencdogan@bilgekaangencdogan:~/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc$ yarn hardhat deploy
yarn run v1.22.22
warning package.json: No license field
$ /home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/.bin/hardhat deploy
WARNING: You are currently using Node.js v21.7.3, which is not supported by Hardhat. This can lead to unexpected behavior. See https://hardhat.org/nodejs-versions


Nothing to compile
Local network detected! Deploying mocks...
deploying "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock" (tx: 0x4e74378c5b2b11e352c170557032ab3fee375d54241c07e8580beab5e0cbd769)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 2984688 gas
Mocks Deployed!!
------------------------------------------------------------------
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing /home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/deploy/01-deploy-raffle.js:
Error: invalid address (argument="address", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.7.0) (argument="vrfCoordinatorV2", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:285:21)
    at AddressCoder.Coder._throwError (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/abstract-coder.ts:68:16)
    at AddressCoder.encode (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/address.ts:22:18)
    at /home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/array.ts:71:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/array.ts:54:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/coders/tuple.ts:54:20)
    at AbiCoder.encode (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/abi-coder.ts:111:15)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1215:19)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1061:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:450:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:359:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:192:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:601:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:359:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:192:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:690:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/bilgekaangencdogan/Desktop/FreeCodeCampBlockchain/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:359:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

you can find my related files below
01-deploy-raffles:
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhart-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("1")
module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.logs[0].args.subId
        // Fund the subscription
        // Usually, you'd need the link token on a real network
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }

    const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"]
    const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]
    const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
    const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]
    const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        entranceFee,
        gasLane,
        subscriptionId,
        callbackGasLimit,
        interval,
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })

    // Ensure the Raffle contract is a valid consumer of the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract.
    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, raffle.address)
    }

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, args)
    }
    log("---------------------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]

helper-hardhat-config.js:
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

const networkConfig = {
    11155111: {
        name: "sepolia",
        vrfCoordinatorV2: "0x9DdfaCa8183c41ad55329BdeeD9F6A8d53168B1B",
        entranceFee: ethers.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasLane: "0x787d74caea10b2b357790d5b5247c2f63d1d91572a9846f780606e4d953677ae",
        subscriptionId: "0",
        callbackGasLimit: "500000", //500,000
        interval: "30",
    },
    31337: {
        name: "hardhat",
        entranceFee: ethers.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasLane: "0x787d74caea10b2b357790d5b5247c2f63d1d91572a9846f780606e4d953677ae",
        callbackGasLimit: "500000", //500,000
        interval: "30",
    },
}

const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"]

module.exports = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
}

VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol";

I think there is a conflict with vrfCoordinatorV2 and VRFCoordinatorV2Mock, but I could not resolve it.
Thanks in advance!!
I am trying to deploy script that deploys my smart contract


the sequence of args should be same with constructor. for me i swith the entranceFee and coordiantorAddress then it works!
